# Очистка таблицы каждую 1 минуту

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема с очисткой данных в таблице. Нужно что-бы через некоторое время очищались старые записи, в моем случае это 1 минута.
Пишу

```
<?php
include_once 'setting.php';
$CONNECT = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "DELETE FROM `online` WHERE `time` < SUBTIME(NOW(), '0 0:01:0')");
?>
```

Параметр time в таблице online имеет такой выгляд: **2016-10-13 03:00:50**

### Но работать не хочет(

Все работает, просто в main файл не заинклудил cron задачу. Спасибо всем кто уделил время.

Comment: А так ?
    DELETE FROM `online` WHERE datediff(minute,`time`,NOW()) > 1

Comment: Похоже инструмент подобран не правильно. `redis` с ttl(Time to live) или хранилище в памяти `memcache` с ttl - подойдет лучше. `delete` - особенно если не по индексированному полю, очень дорогая операция.

Answer (score 1):

Для такой задачи вы просто можете использовать CRON(планировщик заданий). На сервере настройте cron и поставьте чтобы сервер сам каждую минуту вызывал файл(в котором находится sql для удаления) и.. всё )) можете прочитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM `online` WHERE `time` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;
```

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, не помогает(

Comment: проверил на соединение с БД все работает. Почему не хочет удалять записи...